# Reverse for 'django_markdown_preview' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Tags: python, html, django, django-markdown-deux

I am using django_markdown but it is showing error when I am trying to render form. The error is on 17th line {{ form }} [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFYFR.png). The error is in reverse of 'django_markdown_preview', but I have included

```
url('^markdown/', include('django_markdown.urls')),
```

in my urls.py. Can anyone help me to resolve the error.

```
{% extends 'qaforum/base.html' %}
{% load django_markdown %}

{% block content %}

  {% if message %}
  <strong>Enter a valid Question!</strong>
  {% endif %}

  <form method="post" action="{% block action_url %}{% url 'qaforum:qaforum_create_question' %}{% endblock action_url %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
      <tr>
        <th>{{ field.label_tag }}</th>
        <td>
          {{ field.errors }}
          {{ field }}
          {{ field.help_text }}
        </td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}

    <input class="btn pull-right btn-success" type="submit" value="Submit Question" />
  </form>

</div>

{% endblock content %}

{% block extra_js %}
  {% markdown_editor "#id_description" %}
  {% markdown_media %}
{% endblock extra_js %}
```

Comment: why not using django-markdownx, i can tell you how to set it up, [preview](https://github.com/neutronX/django-markdownx#preview)

Comment: Thanks I switched to django-markdownx, but one problem with markdownx is it doesn't give markdown editor. It is just plain text editor.

Comment: make sure in the models replace TextField with `MarkdownxField()` after importing `from markdownx.models import MarkdownxField`